# How to integrate gtest universally in my project (Non Cmake project)

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, googletest

I am using gtest in my Visual Studio Project and want to integrate gtest into it for eg might be using a submodule.I have read several approaches which are all related to CMAKE.
Is there a way where we can integrate Google test library within our project.
I dont mean the conventional way of keeping the lib in C:/lib folder.
Looking for a approach where users clone the project and dependencies are integrated within

Answer (score 0):

You can copy/paste the Google Test project to you solution:

- Download Google Test sources.
- Create a Visual Studio solution and project using CMake with something like this (but check the build instructions):

```
cmake -Dgtest_force_shared_crt=ON .
```

- Copy the project folder from this solution to your solution.
- Open your solution in Visual Studio.
- Right click the solution in the Solution Explorer and choose Add, Existing Project... .
- Select the copied Google Test project.
- Optionally configure project dependencies, include/link paths and build order.